# Convert xml string to java object : getting `details` as null?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have been trying to convert xml string to Java object.

There is a root tag of TV . There are multiple fields inside this but I want the whole content as one String.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TV")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TV {
    @XmlElement
    public String details;
    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TV [details=" + details + "]";
    }   
}


public class XMLtoJavaObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlString = "<TV version=\"0.91fn\"><channel><title>Friends</title><link>https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/</link><season>2</season></channel></TV>";
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TV.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            TV tv = (TV) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
            System.out.println("TV" + tv);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
TV [details=null]
```

I am not getting whole nested xml as String.

Can somebody help me what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is that Your `TV` class doesn't reflect Your `XML` string. There is no `details` field there etc. Try to create `Channel channel` field with and class as well. And Channel class with `title` field and check if it parses.

Comment: Can't I get the whole nested channel tag as one string?

Comment: In the resulting string do you need also the tags or just the values? Could you provide the expected result based on the example in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`TV` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TV")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TV {

    @XmlElement
    private Channel channel;

    public Channel getChannel() {
      return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
      this.channel = channel;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "TV [channel=" + channel + "]";
    }
}
```

`Channel` class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Channel {
  @XmlElement
  private String title;
  private String link;
  private String season;

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getLink() {
    return link;
  }

  public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
  }

  public String getSeason() {
    return season;
  }

  public void setSeason(String season) {
    this.season = season;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Channel [title=" + title + ", link=" + link + ", season=" + season + "]";
  }

}
```

Output:

```
TVTV [channel=Channel [title=Friends, link=https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/, season=2]]
```

And now You can get Your details using Java as You want e.g.:

```
tv.getChannel().getTitle();
```

Comment: No, this is not what i need. I need the whole as one string.

Comment: What about building a `String by Your own by concatenating needed values? Does Your XML structure changes often?

Answer (score 1):

Another answser:

`TV` class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TV")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TV {

    @XmlAnyElement
    private org.w3c.dom.Element channel;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "TV [channel=" + channel + "]";
    }

    public org.w3c.dom.Element getChannel() {
      return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(org.w3c.dom.Element channel) {
      this.channel = channel;
    }

}
```

Then You get text content like this:

```
System.out.println("text: " +  tv.getChannel().getTextContent());
```

Output:

```
text: Friendshttps://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/2
```

Note that it is all texts just concatenated.
But having an `Element` You can iterate recursively through all children and print them together with tag names and text values.

Here is a sample recursive method:
`channel` field name needs to be a `Node` type:

```
....
private org.w3c.dom.Node channel;
....

private static String build(Node element) {
  final String result;
  if (element instanceof Text) {
    result = element.getNodeValue();
  } else {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<").append(element.getNodeName()).append(">");
    for (int i = 0; i < element.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
      final Node child = element.getChildNodes().item(i);
      sb.append(build(child));
    }
    sb.append("</").append(element.getNodeName()).append(">");
    result = sb.toString();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Called like this:

```
  System.out.println(build(tv.getChannel()));
```

Output:

```
<channel><title>Friends</title><link>https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/</link><season>2</season></channel>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Zolv. This helps. In case jaxb can't do I might have to use this.. But hoping something can answer based on JAXB.